# How to remove array in blade - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

i am calling a column from different table to display it in the current table like showing below:

```
DB::table('tbl_users')
->where('id', $complaints->user_id)
->limit(1)
->get('phone');
```

and this is the current output:

```
[{"phone":"0123456789"}]
```

how can i achieve the output to be like this:

```
0123456789
```

i tried to encode/decode and tried to wrap the whole query with json but none of that worked

UPDATE:

controller:

```
public function index()
{


    $complaint = DB::table('complaint')->get();
    $phone = DB::table('tbl_users')
->where('id', $complaint->user_id)
->select('phone')
->first();

    return view('admin.complaints',compact('complaint','phone'));
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($complaint as $complaints)
     <tr>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $complaints->id }}</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $complaints->createdDate }}</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">New</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $complaints->user_id }}</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{$phone->phone}}</th>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need only one record , so you can use `first()` method instead of `limit()` and `get()`.get() method will return multidimensional array.

```
    $user = DB::table('tbl_users')
    ->where('id', $complaints->user_id)
    ->select('phone')
    ->first();

   return view('urBladeFileName', compact('user'));
```

and in your view file

```
{{$user->phone}}
```

**Updated**

use [join](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins) query

```
$complaints = DB::table('complaint')
    ->select(['complaint.id','complaint.createdDate','complaint.user_id','complaint.createdDate','tbl_users.phone'])
    ->join('tbl_users', 'complaint.user_id', '=', 'tbl_users.id')
    ->get();

return view('admin.complaints',compact('complaints'));
```

and in your view

```
  @foreach ($complaints as $complaint)
     <tr>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $complaint->id }}</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $complaint->createdDate }}</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">New</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $complaint->user_id }}</th>
     <th style="padding: 20px">{{$complaint->phone}}</th>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, stdClass given`

Comment: @Sam can you post how you pass data to view and blade code as well.

Comment: @Sam updated answer

Comment: i have updated my question with the controller and getting this error `Property [user_id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: @Sam you can remove ->select('phone') from query and for beter understanding you must show blade file code

Comment: removed it and updated the question with blade and still getting the same error

Comment: @Sam updated answer